# Build Scala against different versions of external API

Tags: scala, dependencies

I'm writing a small library which I'd like to be backwards compatible with older versions of an API, yet use features of the latest API when possible.

So for example, I have a project which uses an external API, which I'll call FooFoo_v1.

Initially, my code looked like this:

```scala
// in Widget.scala
val f = new Foo
f.bar
```

Foo has since released a new version of their API, FooFoo_v2, which adds the `bat` method.  So long as I'm compiling against the new version, this works fine:

```scala
// in Widget.scala
val f = new Foo
f.bar
f.bat
```

But if you try to build against FooFoo_v1, the build obviously fails.  Since the `bat` feature is truly optional, and I'd like to allow folks to build my code against FooFoo_v1 or FooFoo_v2.

Ignoring the details of the dependency management, what's the right high level approach for something like this?  My aim is to keep it as simple as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should split your library in two pieces - one with features used from FooFoo_v1, another depending on the first one and on FooFoo_v2 and using features from FooFoo_v2. How to accomplish it depends on your code... If it's too difficult it's better to follow @rex-kerr advice - to maintain two branches.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply keep separate branches of the project in a repository (one which is sufficiently robust to allow you to edit one and merge effortlessly into the others--git would be my first choice).

If you must do the selection at runtime, then you're limited to using reflection for any new methods.